# emma-maven-plugin not honouring ordering of dependencies?

Tags: maven, dependencies, classpath, emma

I have a Maven project where the order of the dependencies is important. Everything builds just fine. The tests run just fine.

Unfortunately, some of the unit tests break running 'mvn site' because we have emma-maven-plugin configured. The same unit tests also break when running 'mvn emma:emma'.

Is there any way to control the classpath which emma-maven-plugin uses, or to force it to use the dependency ordering specified in the project?

The emma-maven-plugin I'm using is org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3.

Thanks,

PS. I am aware of JaCoCo (jacoco-maven-plugin), and will get round to this is due course, but for now, I'm stuck with Emma

Comment: Why is the order of dependencies or to be more accurate the order of in the classorder important ? Sounds like you have duplicate dependencies or different versions ?

Comment: I'm deliberately overriding a class from a 3rd party whose package name is fixed, and I thought it would be easier than re-packaging their .jar